# No reverse error in Google App Engine Django patch?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-urls

I am using [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) patch Django.

When I try to go to the admin site,

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/

, I keep getting this error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
>   Caught an exception while rendering: Reverse for
>   'settings.django.contrib.auth.views.logout' with arguments
>   '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

It's a fresh installation and I have not changed much. But I
am not able to solve this problem.

This is the urls.py file that comes with the patch inside
the registration app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Activation keys get matched by \w+ instead of the more specific
    # [a-fA-F0-9]{40} because a bad activation key should still get to
    # that way it can return a sensible "invalid key" message instead
    # confusing 404.
    url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
        activate,
        name='registration_activate'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        auth_views.login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
        name='auth_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$',
        auth_views.logout,
        name='auth_logout'),
    url(r'^password/change/$',
        auth_views.password_change,
        name='auth_password_change'),
    url(r'^password/change/done/$',
        auth_views.password_change_done,
        name='auth_password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password/reset/$',
        auth_views.password_reset,
        name='auth_password_reset'),
    url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>.+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
        name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_complete,
        name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
        auth_views.password_reset_done,
        name='auth_password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^register/$',
        register,
        name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^register/complete/$',
        direct_to_template,
        {'template': 'registration/registration_complete.html'},
        name='registration_complete'),
)
```

Comment: I don't know what's happening here, but I think there's a clue in that it gives the name of the view as beginning with 'settings.django.contrib', which is a bit weird. Do you have a setting for ROOT_URLCONF in your settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find a proper answer to my question. Anyways I solved the problem temporarily by reinstalling the Django framework and the app engine SDK.